# ffmpeg - streaming an rtsp stream to a webpage

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, rtsp

I am trying to stream a `rtsp` stream to a webpage.

I have started the `ffserver` as follows:

```
ffserver -d -f /etc/ffserver.conf
```

Here is the command I have spliced together:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -an -i rtsp://admin:password@my_rstp_url:port/ch01/0 -f mpegts http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

This starts up, then fails with this error:

```
Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:0.
```

Here is the full output:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.4-2 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:t1mmo123@192.168.1.120:7320/ch01/0':
  Metadata:
    title           : -
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.040000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mpeg2video (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_alaw (native) -> mp2 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:0.577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
Conversion failed!
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone who finds this thread in the future, I have found an easier solution using [Shinobi](https://shinobi.video/docs/) which does the hard work for me. I can then restream the rtsp stream to mjpeg, mp4 etc.